# Syntax Error unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I am trying to create a form that inputs data to my database however I am getting a syntax error unexpected T_String on line 56. The line in question is my SQL Insert statement but I can't find my error. My code is included below and any help would really be appreciated.

```
        foreach ($postNameArr as $postName){
        if (array_key_exists($postName, $_POST)){
            $w = "INSERT INTO tblContent('PageHeading', 'SubHeading', 'Content', 'PageTitle', 'MetaDescription', 'MetaKeywords') VALUES (["ph"],["sh"],["pc"],["pt"],["md"],["mk"])";
            //if it works...
            if ($conn->query($w) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            }
            //error handling
         else {
            echo "Error: " . $w . "<br>" . $conn->error."');";
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code highlighter in the question itself shows there are strings that shouldn't be there. You need to escape your quotes `\"` or change then double quotes inside your `VALUES` to single quotes.

Comment: you're also using the wrong identifiers for your columns.

Comment: Why do you have the values inside square brackets? MySQL doesn't use that syntax in its queries.

Comment: Did you mean to write `$_POST["ph"]` instead of just `["ph"]`?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: You are mixing double and single quotes in the insert statement without escaping the additional double quotes. You should wrap your db values with single quotes.

Comment: change from `["ph"]`  to `$_POST[\"ph\"]` in all values...

Comment: What exactly do you think `"...VALUES (["ph"],["sh"],["pc"],["pt"],["md"],["mk"])";` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes in your `VALUES` clause are ending the string literal. However, rather than showing how to fix that, the best way to do this is using a prepared query.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tblContent(`PageHeading`, `SubHeading`, `Content`, `PageTitle`, `MetaDescription`, `MetaKeywords`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $_POST["ph"],$_POST["sh"],$_POST["pc"],$_POST["pt"],$_POST["md"],$_POST["mk"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Also, the quotes that should go around table and column names are backticks, not single or double quotes -- those make string literals. But you don't usually need them at all, you only need them when the name conflicts with a MySQL reserved word or contains special characters.

Answer (score -1):

i did not understant this part

```
         (["ph"],["sh"],["pc"],["pt"],["md"],["mk"])
```

if ph,sh,pc are define  you should write in double quotes.

```
        (".ph.",".sh."...)
```

you must put php verable in quotes.
if your start with singel quotes
you should put php variable in singel quotes
for example

```
    $gettest="hello booboo !";
    $singel= ' i start with single quoes  so i put my variable in singel quotes '.$gettest.' ';
    $double= " i start with double quoes  so i put my variable in double quotes ".$gettest." ";

echo $singel."<br>";
echo $double."<br>";
```